# Делимость n! на n^2 C++

Tags: c++, математика, теория-чисел

Как проверить делимость n! на n во второй степени ( n<sup>2</sup> )?

Comment: Так `n!` (в заголовке) или `!n` (в тексте)? :) Смотрите, на `n` точно делится - вам в результате надо проверять делимость `(n-1)!` на `n`.

Это уже можно делать самыми разными способами - вычисляя НОД, раскладывая на множители... а можно и теоретически. См., например, https://www.problems.ru/view_problem_details_new.php?id=78516

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, не согласен

Comment: @TigerTV.ru , да, я и не собирался отвечать, тем более, что вопрос не ваш.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Ну... возьмем `n=4`. 4! = 1x2x3x4 = 24. На 16 не делится... :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ладно, попытаюсь изложить, почему почти (с одним исключением) прав Юрий Козлов. Увы, он удалил свой комментарий, в котором было написано, что для простых чисел n! на n<sup>2</sup> не делится, а для составных - делится.

Поскольку n! всегда делится на n, разделим. Теперь нам остается только проверить делимость (n-1)! на n. Очевидно, что если число *n* простое, то среди сомножителей (n-1)! его не будет, и делиться (n-1)! на n не будет.

Осталось разобраться с составными.

Любое составное число представимо в виде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

произведения простых чисел в каких-то степенях. Если в этом разложении есть хотя бы два простых числа, то, во-первых, у них нет общих делителей, а во-вторых, каждый сомножитель строго меньше n, так все сомножители входят в (n-1)!, а значит, делимость обеспечена.

Осталось рассмотреть случай, когда

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Случай k = 1 соответствует простому числу и уже рассмотрен. Для делимости (n-1)! на p<sup>k</sup> требуется, чтобы p как минимум k раз входило в (n-1)!, т.е. выполнялось условие pk < n, или pk < p<sup>k</sup>, или p<sup>k-1</sup> > k при k >= 2 (единицу мы уже с негодованием отвергли :)) Методом матиндукции очень легко показать, что для любого p > 1 если p<sup>k-1</sup> > k, то для k+1 это справедливо и подавно. Главное - чтоб выполнялось начальное условие. А **не** выполняется оно для k==2 только для одного числа - p==2. Но уже для p==2 и k==3 все работает, и матиндукция справедлива. Таким образом,

(n-1)! **не** делится на n только для n простых и для n==4.

Соответственно, то же справедливо и для n! и n<sup>2</sup>.

Так что на C++ надо реализовать проверку на простоту и на равенство 4...

Comment: Осталась интрига, что же писал Юрий Козлов)

Comment: Он удалил свой комментарий, там было - что для простых не делится. для составных - делится.

Comment: А, теперь понятно